# Qt 5.4 QML VideoOutput not working on iOS

Tags: ios, qt, video, qml, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to play a video with sound in an iOS application with Qt or Qml.
My environment is :

- Qt 5.4
- OSX Yosemite 10.10.2
- iPad 2 (iOS 8.3) and Iphone6+ (iOS 8.3)

Test code (QML version):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtMultimedia 5.0    

VideoOutput {
   anchors.fill: parent
   fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectFit
   source: player

   MediaPlayer {
       id: player
       autoPlay: true
       onStatusChanged: {if (status==MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia) play();}
       source: "qrc:/videos/vid2.mp4"
   }
}
```

Test code (C++ version):

```
QMainWindow w;

QVideoWidget* pVWidget = new QVideoWidget;
QMediaPlayer* pPlayer = new QMediaPlayer;

pPlayer->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/videos/vid2.mp4"));

w.setCentralWidget(pVWidget);
w.show();

pPlayer->play();
```

My project file (`.pro`):

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += core gui network sql widgets xmlpatterns quick qml multimedia multimediawidgets

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

Source tested :

- from resource: `qrc://videos/vid2.mp4`
- from local file after successfull copy on the storage : `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/12BD0B54-46B3-439F-9869-E06E1AC6CD87/Library/Application Support/data/vid1.mp4`
- from video online : `http://www.rmh.de/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6/9d0386eada217cd63a752458aeca89d6.mp4`

Everything works fine when executed Android or OS X whereas execution fails both on iOS devices and iOS Simulator.

I tried adding the `QTPLUGING` but, as it should be, Creator found that it was duplicating. I tried using `QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA` but that didn't work either. I got a white screen on QML version and black screen on C++ version.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there any output on the console ("Application output" pane in Qt Creator)?

Comment: No nothing, no error message, no warning...

Comment: I just found that when I check the onStatusChanged of MediaPlayer, this one stop on MediaPlayer.InvalidMedia with error string "Failed to load media".

An other discovery is that if I load my qml from the Documents folder of the app, the video is stating... (with some other issues of layout, but starting...).
If I start exactly the same qml file from the resources, no video start.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Qt bug.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31422
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-36175

Fixed in Qt 5.5 supposedly.